# Solving for third derivative of implicit differentiation

Tags: derivatives

My professor gave us an activity of, to me what feels like, a vague third derivative implicit differentiation. We were taught up to second, but now I am feeling lost.

I am tasked to find $\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}$, $x^2$+$y^2$=$a^2$.

I treated $a^2$ as a constant like what tutorial videos online did, and arrived at a different answer: $\frac{x}{27y^5}$. None of the choices match this in the question given to me, they all include ***a*** in them. Am I looking at $a^2$ differently here?

Comment: Please post the question directly, via text, into the post. Don't force anyone to chase your link.

Comment: Apologies. Updated.

Comment: Thanks, @hideme. Nice job!

Comment: If we don't see what you have done, it's very difficult to spot what error you have made... if you've made one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For general $a$ the answer should be

$$y'''(x) = \frac{-3a^2x}{|y|^{5}}.$$

To see this, we take the equation $x^2+y^2=a^2$ and differentiate it several times. The first, second and third derivatives give

$$2(x+yy') =0$$
$$ 2(1+ y'^2+ y y'')=0$$
$$6y'y'' +2yy'''=0$$
respectively, precisely because as you say, $a$ is a constant.

The first equation can be solved for $y'$ in terms of $y$. The second equation can be solved for $y''$ in terms of $y$ and $y'$ and hence, substituting the form of $y'$, this yields $y''$ in terms of just $y$. Finally the third equation can be solved for $y'''$ in terms of $y,y'$ and $y''$, and by substituting the previously found expressions of $y'$ and $y''$ this gives us a formula for $y'''$ in terms of $y$. It is given by

$$y'''(x) = \frac{-3x(x^2 + y^2)}{y^5}.$$

We can simplify this by using the fact that $x^2 + y^2=a^2$, so that

$$y'''(x) = \frac{-3xa^2}{y^5}.$$

This looks a lot like your answer, so perhaps you just made an error somewhere. Another possibility is that it has been specified somewhere that $a = 1/9$. In that case we would get exactly your answer, up to a minus sign.

EDIT: By the way, I just realized another possibility is that this was not meant as an implicit differentiation exercise (as is not completely clear from your question). Indeed the equation $x^2+y^2=a^2$ simply implies a formula for $y(x)$, namely

$$y(x) = \pm \sqrt{a^2-x^2}.$$

Perhaps the goal is simply to explicitly differentiate this expression three times.

Comment: Your first assumption was spot on! Now as clear as day! Thank you very much.